# How can I do Base64 encoding in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, encoding, base64

Does Node.js have built-in Base64 encoding yet?

The reason why I ask this is that `final()` from `crypto` can only output hexadecimal, binary or ASCII data. For example:

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3-cbc', encryption_key, iv);
var ciph = cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf8', 'hex');
ciph += cipher.final('hex');

var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('des-ede3-cbc', encryption_key, iv);
var txt = decipher.update(ciph, 'hex', 'utf8');
txt += decipher.final('utf8');
```

According to the documentation, `update()` can output Base64-encoded data. However, `final()` doesn't support Base64. I tried and it will break.

If I do this:

```
var ciph = cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf8', 'base64');
    ciph += cipher.final('hex');
```

Then what should I use for decryption? Hexadecimal or Base64?

Therefore, I'm looking for a function to Base64-encode my encrypted hexadecimal output.

Comment: For someone looking for this problem in/after 2016 `cipher.final('base64')` works

Comment: try base122 https://github.com/kevinAlbs/Base122

Answer (score 2731, accepted):

[Buffers](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html) can be used for taking a string or piece of data and doing Base64 encoding of the result. For example:

```
> console.log(Buffer.from("Hello World").toString('base64'));
SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=
> console.log(Buffer.from("SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=", 'base64').toString('ascii'))
Hello World
```

The `Buffer` constructor is a global object, so no require is needed. Buffers created with strings can take an optional encoding parameter to specify what encoding the string is in. The available `toString` and `Buffer` constructor encodings are as follows:

> 'ascii' - for 7 bit ASCII data only. This encoding method is very
> fast, and will strip the high bit if set.
>
> 'utf8' - Multi byte encoded
> Unicode characters. Many web pages and other document formats use
> UTF-8.
>
> 'ucs2' - 2-bytes, little endian encoded Unicode characters. It
> can encode only BMP(Basic Multilingual Plane, U+0000 - U+FFFF).
>
> 'base64' - Base64 string encoding.
>
> 'binary' - A way of encoding raw
> binary data into strings by using only the first 8 bits of each
> character. This encoding method is deprecated and should be avoided in
> favor of Buffer objects where possible. This encoding will be removed
> in future versions of Node.

Comment: `const atob = (data) => Buffer.from(data, 'base64').toString('ascii');`

Comment: that should be `.toString("binary")` (`atob` stands for ascii(base64) to binary, after all)

Comment: @12Me21 I thought it stood for ascii to base64?

Comment: @DavidCallanan atob() converts from base64

Comment: I got this warning after `Buffer.from` (node:13765) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

Comment: I have a related question that I think you'll know the answer to. I appreciate your help! https://stackoverflow.com/q/75416587/470749

Comment: "Buffers are a global object, so no require is needed." The NodeJS docs recommend "to explicitly reference it via an import or require statement."

Answer (score 383):

The accepted answer [previously contained](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6182519/3) `new Buffer()`, which is considered a security issue in Node.js versions greater than 6 (although it seems likely for this use case that the input can always be coerced to a string).

The `Buffer` constructor is deprecated according to [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer_from_buffer_alloc_and_buffer_allocunsafe).

The code snippets should read:

```
console.log(Buffer.from("Hello World").toString('base64'));
console.log(Buffer.from("SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=", 'base64').toString('ascii'));
```

After this answer was written, it has been updated and now matches this.

Comment: When I try to use your first line, Node returns:
[TypeError: this is not a typed array.]

Comment: This error happens on node versions older than v6. In these versions you'll need to use the constructor (`new Buffer`) rather than `Buffer.from`.

Comment: [Buffer.from()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_array) was added in v4.5.0.

Comment: Just to save you few minutes that I lost trying to see difference between this example and the one in the accepted answer, the accepted answer is now updated to what this answer suggests.

Comment: What is the "ws" library? Can you add a reference to? But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Answer (score 53):

`crypto` now supports Base64 ([reference](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_final_output_encoding)):

```
cipher.final('base64')
```

So you could simply do:

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3-cbc', encryption_key, iv);
var ciph = cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf8', 'base64');
ciph += cipher.final('base64');

var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('des-ede3-cbc', encryption_key, iv);
var txt = decipher.update(ciph, 'base64', 'utf8');
txt += decipher.final('utf8');
```

Comment: Any reason to use this over NotJavanese's answer?

Comment: Had to match encryptions between Node and Python and this answer saved me a question! Thanks :)

Comment: This is incorrect since you can't just append multiple base64 strings and get a correctly concatenated base64 string. This only works if the update function returns chunks of length divisible by 4, of which there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 12):

***Buffers*** can be used for taking a string or piece of data and doing Base64 encoding of the result. For example:

You can install **Buffer** via npm like: `npm i buffer --save`

You can use this in your `js` file like this:

```
var buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer;

->> console.log(buffer.from("Hello Vishal Thakur").toString('base64'));
SGVsbG8gVmlzaGFsIFRoYWt1cg==  // Result

->> console.log(buffer.from("SGVsbG8gVmlzaGFsIFRoYWt1cg==", 'base64').toString('ascii'))
Hello Vishal Thakur   // Result
```

Comment: `buffer` should be capitalized to `Buffer`

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms as you can see i have imported this `require('buffer/').Buffer;` at last, you can see `Buffer`.

Answer (score 3):

I am using the following code to decode a Base64 string in the Node.js API, Node.js version 10.7.0:

```
let data = 'c3RhY2thYnVzZS5jb20=';  // Base64 string
let buff = new Buffer(data, 'base64');  //Buffer
let text = buff.toString('ascii');  // This is the data type that you want your Base64 data to convert to
console.log('"' + data + '" converted from Base64 to ASCII is "' + text + '"');
```

Please don't try to run the above code in the console of the browser. It won't work. Put the code in the server-side files of Node.js. I am using the above line code in API development.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this :

```
console.log(Buffer.from("Hello World").toString('base64'));
console.log(Buffer.from("SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=", 'base64').toString('ascii'));
```

This will convert a string into base64 encoded string i.e. `SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=` and then you can decode it back to `Hello World`

Answer (score -3):

I have created an ultimate small JavaScript [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/nodejs-base64-converter) library for the Base64 encode/decode conversion in Node.js.

#### Installation

```
npm install nodejs-base64-converter --save
```

#### Usage

```
var nodeBase64 = require('nodejs-base64-converter');

console.log(nodeBase64.encode("test text")); //dGVzdCB0ZXh0
console.log(nodeBase64.decode("dGVzdCB0ZXh0")); //test text
```

Comment: no need to install an extra plugin when it is natively supported by nodejs

Answer (score -3):

You can do Base64 encoding and decoding with simple JavaScript.

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val(),
        hash = Base64.encode(value);
    $(".test").html(hash);

    var decode = Base64.decode(hash);

    $(".decode").html(decode);
});

var Base64 = {_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/rn/g,"n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}

// Define the string
var string = 'Hello World!';

// Encode the string
var encodedString = Base64.encode(string);
console.log(encodedString); // Outputs: "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"

// Decode the string
var decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedString);
console.log(decodedString); // Outputs: "Hello World!"</script></div>
```

This is implemented in this [Base64 encoder decoder](https://www.asciicharacter.com/p/base64-encoder-decoder.html).

Comment: Perhaps update it for "[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)" (not "Hello World!")?