# Convert Binary.toString('encode64') back to Binary

Tags: node.js, encoding, binary-data

I've seen [several](https://gist.github.com/583836) [tutorial](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/buffers.html) explaining how to convert binary image into encode64 representations:

```
var image = new Buffer(bl.toString(), 'binary').toString('base64');
```

My question is, how to return this string representation, back to it's buffer's binary data.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This question has some helpful info: [How to do Base64 encoding in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182315/how-to-do-base64-encoding-in-node-js)

The Buffer class itself does the conversion:

```
var base64data = Buffer.from('some binary data', 'binary').toString('base64');

console.log(base64data);
// ->  'c29tZSBiaW5hcnkgZGF0YQ=='

var originaldata = Buffer.from(base64data, 'base64');

console.log(originaldata);
// ->  <Buffer 73 6f 6d 65 20 62 69 6e 61 72 79 20 64 61 74 61>

console.log(originaldata.toString());
// ->  some binary data
```

Comment: I have a related question that I think you'll know the answer to. I appreciate your help! https://stackoverflow.com/q/75416587/470749

Answer (score 6):

`new Buffer` is deprecated

From Binary to base64:

```
const base64data = Buffer.from('some binary data', 'binary').toString('base64');
console.log(base64data);
// ->  'c29tZSBiaW5hcnkgZGF0YQ=='
```

From base64 to binary:

```
 const origionalData = Buffer.from('some base64 data', 'base64') 

console.log(origionalData) 

// ->  'c29tZSBiaW5hcnkgZGF0YQ=='
```