# How to send email in javascript or python from specific email account?

Tags: javascript, python, email

I have an html file on my computer that takes an email address (gmail) and a password as input. I want to use javascript or python to log into the gmail acount with the given email address and send a message to another email address. How would I do this? Either javascript or python is fine.

Comment: Yikes!  I sure hope you have some solid security in place...sounds like an easy way to get access to people's email accounts.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html

Comment: It's too general a question, mixing too many things. Do the tutorial just linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From Google](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/):

> "Gmail supports the standard IMAP and SMTP protocols for accessing and
>   sending e-mail messages. The Gmail IMAP and SMTP servers have been
>   extended to support authorization via the industry-standard OAuth 2.0
>   protocol."

So it looks like with an  OAuth STMP/IMAP Javascript library you should be able to make this work.  See this SO article for an example: [Connecting to the Gmail IMAP API in javascript/node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9795794/573083)

Another option is to take a look at the [Gmailr API](http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/02/05/introducing-gmailr-an-unofficial-javscript-api-for-gmail/).

While this is not going to be a plug-and-play solution for you, it's the course that most of the early 3rd party gmail extenders apparently used.