# NodeJS: How to decode base64 encoded string back to binary?

Tags: node.js, encoding, base64, decoding

I was implementing password hashing with salt, so I generated salt as binary, hashed the password, base64 encoded the password and salt then stored them into database.

Now when I am checking password, I am supposed to decode the salt back into binary data, use it to hash the supplied password, base64 encode the result and check if the result matches the one in database.

The problem is, I cannot find a method to decode the salt back into binary data. I encoded them using the Buffer.toString method but there doesn't seem to be reverse function.

Answer (score 822, accepted):

**As of Node.js v6.0.0** using [the constructor method has been deprecated](https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.0.0/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_str_encoding) and the following method should instead be used to construct a new buffer from a base64 encoded string:

```
var b64string = /* whatever */;
var buf = Buffer.from(b64string, 'base64'); // Ta-da
```

**For Node.js v5.11.1 and below**

Construct a new `Buffer` and [pass `'base64'` as the second argument:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6182519/139010)

```
var b64string = /* whatever */;
var buf = new Buffer(b64string, 'base64'); // Ta-da
```

If you want to be clean, you can check whether `from` exists :

```
if (typeof Buffer.from === "function") {
    // Node 5.10+
    buf = Buffer.from(b64string, 'base64'); // Ta-da
} else {
    // older Node versions, now deprecated
    buf = new Buffer(b64string, 'base64'); // Ta-da
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately their documentation isn't clear on this function ... (http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/buffers.html#new_Buffer)

Comment: It's not _that_ bad, the 3rd constructor is right there.

Comment: So how do we know if it returns invalid? Where's the documentation?

Comment: And for those searching the reverse method - `( new Buffer( str ) ).toString( "base64" )`.

Comment: This method has been deprecated now, the correct way is now:
`var buf = Buffer.from(b64string, 'base64');`
as noted here: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings

Comment: @KristofferDorph thanks for the updated info. Would you mind suggesting an edit to this answer, please?

Comment: The part that @nathanhleung mentioned should be part of the answer!

Comment: FYI, this code does not appear to work on older Node versions. Buffer.from is still a function on node 4.3.6, but 'TypeError: base64 is not a function'

Comment: @Doug, it was raising this unclear error for me too, had to upgrade node and it started working.

Comment: If `toString('ascii')` isn't working for you, try this instead: `Buffer.from(string, 'base64').toString('utf-8')`

Comment: Use decode  string from base64 to string : let text = Buffer.from(imgurl, "base64").toString("utf-8");

Comment: You got it wrong. It is `const buf = Buffer.from('abc', 'utf-8').toString('base64');`

Comment: Just want to say that using Buffer that way in Node seems to be deprecated. A prefered way to do this would be: `const binary = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64');`

Comment: To add some to the reverse method, you can decode them by calling atob(). ```const a = new Buffer(str).toString('base64'); const decodedData = atob(a)```