# Converting mongodb Binary _id to LUUID using node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bson, mongoexport

I'm trying to move data from mongodb to mysql

I used `mongoexport` in order to export the data from the mongodb database to .json files

When I browse my mongodb collection using robomongo I'm getting ids in a Legacy UUID format (something like `LUUID("00018e06-1de9-aa45-afb5-a2bc00ed94f7")` but in the exported .json files it appears this way: 
`{ "_id" : { "$binary" : "AAGOBh3pqkWvtaK8AO2U9w==", "$type" : "03" }, ...}`

It there any way to convert the latter to the format I see in robomongo using Node.JS?

P.S I've seen many Q&A that reference Binary and BinData - but non of them have shown how to convert it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, first off `$binary` and `BinData` are basically the same thing written/represented different ways.  Using your example and [this reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#data_binary) you can write it like so in the "Mongo Shell" mode:

```
BinData(3,"AAGOBh3pqkWvtaK8AO2U9w==")
```

Or in "strict" mode that becomes:

```
{ "$binary" : "AAGOBh3pqkWvtaK8AO2U9w==", "$type" : "03" }
```

Now, type 3 here actually refers to subtype 3 (of the binary type) per the [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) which means this is a "UUID (old)" subtype.  Per the reference above, the string itself is actually a `base64` representation of a binary string.  Because of this (I am inferring) `robomongo` is basically converting the UUID and displaying it for you when you are browsing the data.  Let's attempt to do that manually instead in the `mongo` shell, first by converting it to hex:

```
> var foo = BinData(3, "AAGOBh3pqkWvtaK8AO2U9w==")
> foo.hex()
00018e061de9aa45afb5a2bc00ed94f7
```

Now, let's plug that into a UUID constructor and see if it translates back:

```
> var uuid = new UUID("00018e061de9aa45afb5a2bc00ed94f7")
> uuid
BinData(3,"AAGOBh3pqkWvtaK8AO2U9w==")
```

And, it does - all `robomongo` is doing is adding some dashes for readability.  Just for completeness, with your other example I will remove the dashes and create a UUID, show the `BinData` version and convert back:

```
> var bar = UUID("d72f21fe47808040ab3da1fb01045d3a")
> bar
BinData(3,"1y8h/keAgECrPaH7AQRdOg==")
> bar.hex()
d72f21fe47808040ab3da1fb01045d3a
```

Hence, what you need to do is convert between the base64 encoding in node yourself.  I don't have a `node.js` environment to test, but it looks like that has been [covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6182519/1148648) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14573049/1148648) elsewhere on the site.

## EDIT:

This is a working function in Node.JS that converts the binary to Hex UUID:

```
function Bin2HexUUID(bin){
    var hex = new Buffer(bin, 'base64').toString('hex');
    return hex.replace(/^(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})$/, function (){
        return arguments[1]+"-"+arguments[2]+"-"+arguments[3]+"-"+arguments[4]+"-"+arguments[5];
    });
}

//use example
var binary_id = { "$binary" : "AAGOBh3pqkWvtaK8AO2U9w==", "$type" : "03" };
console.log(Bin2HexUUID(binary_id.$binary)); //00018e06-1de9-aa45-afb5-a2bc00ed94f7
```

Comment: When run on Node 14: `[DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues.`

Comment: It should be noted that this answer is 7 years old, not really surprising that things are different on more recent versions

Comment: The Deprecation is simply in how buffer is instantiated, the preferred method is now Buffer.from() ie.  (remove new) Buffer.from(bin, 'base64')