# The "size" argument must be of type number in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql

I want to onverting mongodb Binary _id to UUID using node so in order a googling and find my response at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789342/converting-mongodb-binary-id-to-luuid-using-node/25792240#25792240) :

I want to insert this UUId into postgres database.This is my pg function on node.js:

```
function insert(arg) {
    console.log('insert location');
    arg.forEach(element => {
        (async () => {
            await pool.query(
                `insert into public."Location" ("Id", "Lat", "Lng", "CreationDateTime", "DeviceId", "Topic", "UserId") 
            VALUES ('${uuidv1()}', ${element.Lat}, ${element.Lng}, $1, ${element.DeviceId}, $2, $3)`,[element.CreationDateTime, element.Topic,Bin2HexUUID(element.UserId)]);
        })();
    });
}
```

This is `element.UserId` :

```
Binary {_bsontype: "Binary", sub_type: 4, position: 16, …}
_bsontype:"Binary"
```

and this is `Bin2HexUUID` method:

```
function Bin2HexUUID(bin){
    var hex = new Buffer.alloc(bin, 'base64').toString('hex');
    return hex.replace(/^(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})$/, function (){
        return arguments[1]+"-"+arguments[2]+"-"+arguments[3]+"-"+arguments[4]+"-"+arguments[5];
    });
}
```

When i run script i got this error:

```
new Buffer.alloc(bin, 'base64').toString('hex')
NodeError: The "size" argument must be of type number. Received type object
----------------------
(node:2292) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "size" argument must be of type number. Received type object
```

For first time i used `new Buffer(bin, 'base64').toString('hex')` but seems new Buffer is deprecated..

This is my Node and Npm version:

```
node -v
v10.8.0

npm -v
6.2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed this part

```
Bin2HexUUID(element.UserId)
```

to this:

```
Bin2HexUUID(element.UserId.buffer)]);
```

and method :

```
function Bin2HexUUID(bin){
    var hex = new Buffer.from(bin, 'base64').toString('hex');
    return hex.replace(/^(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})$/, function (){
        return arguments[1]+"-"+arguments[2]+"-"+arguments[3]+"-"+arguments[4]+"-"+arguments[5];
    });
}
```

I hope this changes help to guys.

Comment: Yes dude. I got `.buffer` from my UserId binary object and pass to those method and those method return a UUId as a return value @BobRodes

Comment: Glad you got it solved. :) You might come back after 48 hours and [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).

Comment: Sure dude. Thank you  @BobRodes

Answer (score 3):

The `size` argument in`Buffer.alloc(size)`, not unreasonably, requires a number, because it's an argument that tells the method how many bytes to allocate.

Your `Bin2HexUUID(element.UserId)` is passing the `element.UserId` object itself to this method (your error message is telling you that when it says "Received type object"). That's not what the method wants. What it wants is the *size* (length) of `Element.UserId`.

So, get the length of `Element.UserId` and pass that instead.