# Decode Base64 string in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, decoding

I'm trying to decode a base64 string representing an image stored in a db. 
I tried many libraries and solutions provided on SO, but I'm still unable to decode the image correctly. In particular, using the following code:

```
var img = new Buffer(b64, 'base64').toString('ascii');
```

I get a similar binary representation, except for the first bytes. 
This is the initial part of the base64 string:

```
/9j/4RxVRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAANADIBAgAUAAAAqgAAACWIBAABAAAAiwYAABABAgAIAAAAvgAA
```

Here are the first 50 bytes of the original image:

```
ffd8ffe11c5545786966000049492a00080000000d003201020014000000aa00000025880400010000008b06000010010200
```

And here are the first 50 bytes of the string I get with javascript:

```
7f587f611c5545786966000049492a00080000000d0032010200140000002a00000025080400010000000b06000010010200
```

How you can see, the two strings are identical except for the fisrt 3 bytes and some few bytes in the middle.
Can somebody help me understand why this is happening and how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [NodeJS: How to decode base64 encoded string back to binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573001/nodejs-how-to-decode-base64-encoded-string-back-to-binary)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. I already tried that solution and doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to convert binary data to ASCII, which most likely than not, will mean loss of data since ASCII only consists of values 0x00-0x7F. So when the conversion takes place, all bytes > 0x7F are capped at 0x7F.

If you do this instead, you can see the data matches your first 50 bytes of the original image:

```
console.log(Buffer.from(b64, 'base64').toString('hex'));
```

But if you want to keep the binary data intact, just keep it as a Buffer instance without calling `.toString()`, as many functions that work with binary data can deal with Buffers (e.g. `fs` core module).

Comment: I thought it was a character encryption problem but I was sure ascii values could arrive till 0xFF. However replacing `.toString('hex')` doesn't work for me (I get a completely different string), but removing the `.toString()` call did the work, thank you!

Comment: Please be aware that new Buffer has been depreciated, you should see a warning in your logs: "DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
" In mscdex example above use Buffer.from(b64, 'base64').toString('hex')