# TypeError Base64 is not a function when using Buffer.from in Node 4.3

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I am debugging a lambda function locally on Node 4.3 using the standard Amazon Machine Image (linux x64)

When I run the program, I get an error in a function that is meant to decode a base64 string to utf-8.    The error says

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: base64 is not a function
    at Function.from (native)
    at Function.from (native)
    at /home/ec2-user/sass-compiler/lib/compiler.module.js:26:30
```

My code seems rather simple.    I have checked around SO and the [node 4.3 docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v4.x/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_str_encoding) and my code seems compliant.    Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

```
template() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let buf = Buffer.from(this._opts.tpl, 'base64').toString('utf-8');
            let _tpl = _.template(buf);
            resolve(_tpl(this._opts.opts));
        });
    }
```

EDIT The program works just fine on Windows 10 using Node LTS 6.9.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found an answer on Stack Overflow that answers this question.

[NodeJS: How to decode base64 encoded string back to binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573001/nodejs-how-to-decode-base64-encoded-string-back-to-binary)

In node 5.3 & below, you need to use the buffer constructor (ie: `new Buffer`) instead of `Buffer.from`

Comment: `Buffer` class is available globally. Don't import it to avoid the error.