# 'base64 is not a function' error with ngc

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I'm following instructions from https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler to get an AOT build.

As per the [Bootstrap](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#bootstrap) section, you need to switch your main.ts from this:

```
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

to this:

```
import '../aot/App/app.module.ngfactory';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

But, after switching, when i run the `ngc` compiler, I get this error:

```
Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json"
TypeError: base64 is not a function
    at Function.from (native)
    at Function.from (native)
    at Object.extractInlineSourceMap (E:\myapp\Sources\Web\node_modules\tsickle\build\src\source_map_utils.js:33:19)
    at TsickleCompilerHost.stripAndStoreExistingSourceMap (E:\myapp\Sources\Web\node_modules\tsickle\build\src\tsickle_compiler_host.js:128:48)
    at TsickleCompilerHost.getSourceFile (E:\myapp\Sources\Web\node_modules\tsickle\build\src\tsickle_compiler_host.js:89:25)
    at findSourceFile (E:\myapp\Sources\Web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67909:29)
    at processImportedModules (E:\myapp\Sources\Web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:68056:25)
    at findSourceFile (E:\myapp\Sources\Web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67937:17)
    at processSourceFile (E:\myapp\Sources\Web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67840:27)
    at processRootFile (E:\myapp\Sources\Web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67728:13)
Compilation failed
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

I know about the ["Base64 is not a function error in Node.JS 5.3 and below" problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260671/typeerror-base64-is-not-a-function-when-using-buffer-from-in-node-4-3), but I'm using NodeJS v8.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowser }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from './aot/app/app.module.ngfactory';

enableProdMode();
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```