# unable to get the value of decoded base64 data in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects, node-modules

this value was encoded to base64

```
    {
     a: "008078888658936",
     b: "REA"
    }
```

and was decoded using this code

```
    var mytokenvalue = "ewphOiAiMDA4MDc4ODg4NjU4OTM2IiwKYjogIlJFQSIKfQ=="
    let decoded = Buffer.from(token, 'base64')
```

meanwhile, when I try to get the decoded value

```
console.log(decoded.a)
```

I am getting undefined in my console.
Please help

Comment: Its a Buffer, not an object. Use `JSON.parse`

Comment: At `Buffer.from(token`, `token` IS `undefined`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS: How to decode base64 encoded string back to binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573001/nodejs-how-to-decode-base64-encoded-string-back-to-binary)

Comment: -Jonas Wilms  that returns exception: caughtException but no error msgSyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
    var token = "ewphOiAiMDA4MDc4ODg4NjU4OTM2IiwKYjogIlJFQSIKfQ==";
    eval('var decoded = ' + Buffer.from(token, 'base64').toString());
    console.log(decoded.a);
```

But `eval` is extremely dangerous if the base64-encoded string can come from somewhere that is outside your control.  An arbitrary string could expand to some unexpected JavaScript that would cause `eval` to do something that would make your program misbehave or breach security.

It would be better to express the original object as a JSON string (use `JSON.stringify` to do that) and base64-encode that string.  Then you can use `JSON.parse` to reconstruct the original object without taking on the risk of using `eval`.  Like this:

```
    var obj = { x: "foo", y: 123 };
    var obj_json = JSON.stringify(obj);
            // obj_json is '{"x":"foo","y":123}'
    var obj_b64 = Buffer(obj_json).toString('base64');
            // obj_b64 is 'eyJ4IjoiZm9vIiwieSI6MTIzfQ=='
    var decoded = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(obj_b64, 'base64').toString());        
    console.log(decoded.x);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to return the decoded value as a string with `.toString()`.

```js
let token = "ewphOiAiMDA4MDc4ODg4NjU4OTM2IiwKYjogIlJFQSIKfQ==";
let decoded = Buffer.from(token, 'base64').toString();
console.log(decoded);
```

Comment: thanks for duplicating my code, the issue is to get the element of the object. like this console.log(decoded.a);

Comment: Afeez, you're a sweetie :) Some people on here are actually trying to help you.

Comment: The issue is likely a malformed JS object before you encode it. Try this token: "ewogICJhIjogIjAwODA3ODg4ODY1ODkzNiIsCiAgImIiOiAiYWZlZXoiCn0="

Comment: The OP's provided base64 decodes to invalid JSON because the property names are not enclosed with quotations. `{ a : "..." }` is not valid JSON, but `{ "a" : "..." }` is. Assuming the encoded base64 text indeed represents a valid JSON, this is the proper answer.