# Transforming Blob().text() to a File()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, file, blob

I want to send a generated image from a `React` frontend to an `Express` server but since I can't send a `Blob()` object with axios (I get an empty object) my idea was to get the raw image data with `Blob().text()` first, send that to the express backend and transform it back to a `File()` object there (`File()` inherites from `Blob()`) but somehow all I get is an blank squared `png` which was definetly not what I send.

**React**

```js
async mint() { 
    const blob = await htmlToImage.toBlob(document.querySelector('.kryptoweapon'));
    const rawPng = await blob.text();

    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3002/api/mint', { 
        rawPng,
        metadata: this.state 
    });
}
```

**Express (node)**

```js
const { rawPng } = req.body;
const { name, type, blockz, starz } = req.body.metadata;

const nft = {
    name,
    description: '',
    image: new File([rawPng], `blaat.png`, { type: 'image/png' }),
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get image content by using **Blob.text**. It returns bytes in UTF-8 format, which isn't the right format for images.

Otherwise there are 2 options.

### 1) Use FormData instead

It's another content type for HTTP requests, you can read her
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

On client-side

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append('name', yourblob);
```

On Node.js it can be handled for example by a very common library

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

### 2) Encode/Decode to Base64

It's a common encode/decode algorithm which can be performed also with files to get a string
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

On client-side

```
function encodeBase64(blob) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    var base64Result = reader.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}
```

On server-side

You can read her
[NodeJS: How to decode base64 encoded string back to binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573001/nodejs-how-to-decode-base64-encoded-string-back-to-binary)

After collecting the buffer convert it to file, for example with using

```
fs.createWriteStream('your/path/to/store/image').write(buffer);
```

Comment: Turns out It works on the frontend but doesn't on the node side somehow, I send the image to https://nft.storage/, when I send it from the frontend it goes over well but when I do the exact same thing on node it doesn't. Copmplete mystery

Comment: The problem is that you can't use blob.text to get image content, because image, content isn't in UTF-8 format (if easy, its isn't a normal text), as an example you can open your image with text editor. It will show not a normal text. Other easy way to solve, I'll add another answer

Answer (score 0):

**Blob.text()** uses UTF-8 encoding which isn't the right format for images, use **FileReader.readAsText()** instead, which depending on blob's type uses different encoding.

```
const reader = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const result = reader.result;
  //Send this result to Node.js
}, false);

reader.readAsText(yourBlob);
```