# node.js - http with base64

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a node.js newbie stuck trying to implement base64 encoding.  My server doesn't seem to receive/process the base64 message.  Code below:

Server:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  req.on('data',function(b) {
    console.log("HEY!"); // <--- Never gets called
    var content = new Buffer(b, 'base64').toString('utf8')
    console.log("CLIENT SAID: "+content);
    var msg = JSON.parse(content);
    // do stuff and respond here...
  });
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Client:

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
  hostname : 'localhost',
  port     : 1337,
  method   : 'POST'
};
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('base64');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});
req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
var msg = {'name':'Fred','age':23};
var msgS = JSON.stringify(msg);
req.write(msgS,'base64');
req.end();
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182315/how-to-do-base64-encoding-in-node-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a fix. I noticed when using `req.write(data, 'base64');` that the request never ended. I instead created a buffer that was base64 encoded, then wrote it to the request.

These exact snippets were tested localhost:

Client:

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 1337,
  method: 'POST'
};
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  res.setEncoding('base64');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

var msg = {
  'name': 'Fred',
  'age': 23
};
var msgS = JSON.stringify(msg);
var buf = new Buffer(msgS, 'base64');

req.write(msgS);
req.end();
```

Server:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var content = '';
  req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    content += chunk;
  });
  req.on('end', function() {
    content = content.toString('base64');
    console.log(content);
    //content returns {"name": "Fred","age": 23};

    res.end();
  });
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Aside from those things, I noticed these errors in your code.

```
req.on('data',function(b) {
  var content = new Buffer(b, 'base64').toString('utf8')
});
```

Note that `b` in this case is actually already a buffer. You should use `b.toString('base64');`. Also note that `b` is actually only fragments of the data. You should instead collect the data of `b`, then listen to the `end` event to finally do something with the data. In your case with `req.write(data, 'base64');`, the end would never fire, leading to a hangup instead of the event firing.

This is how you'd collect data:

```
var content = '';
req.on('data', function(b) {
  content += b;
});
req.on('end', function() {
  //do something with content
});
```