# get file as text from github v3 api using bash

Tags: bash, base64, github-api

I'm trying to get a config file from our GitHub using the [get contents](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) api.

This returns a JSON containing the file content encoded as a base64 string.

### **I'd like to get it as text**

#### Steps I've taken

1. **get initial api response:**
   `curl -H 'Authorization: token MY_TOKEN' \
   https://github.com/api/v3/repos/MY_OWNER/MY_REPO/contents/MY_FILE`
   *this returns a JSON response with a field `"content": "encoded content ..."`*
2. **get the encoded string:**
   add `<prev command> | grep -F "content\":"`
   *this gets the content, but there's still the `"content":` string, the `"` chars and a comma at the end*
3. **cut the extras:**
   `<prev command> | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -d "\"" -f 2`
4. **decode:**
   `<prev command | base64 --decode>`

final command:
`curl -H 'Authorization: token MY_TOKEN' \
 https://github.com/api/v3/repos/MY_OWNER/MY_REPO/contents/MY_FILE | \
 grep -F "content\":" | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -d "\"" -f 2 | base64 --decode`

#### Issues:

1. the resulting string (before the `base64 --decode`) decodes in an online decoder (not well -> see next item), but fails to do so in **bash**. The response being

   > "Invalid character in input stream."
2. When decoding the string in an [online decoder](https://www.base64decode.org/), some (not all) of the file is in gibberish, and not the original text. I've tried all the available charsets.

#### Notes:

1. I've tried removing the last 2 (newline) chars with `sed 's/..$//'`, but this has no effect.
2. If I select the output with the mouse and copy paste it to a `echo MY_ECODED_STRING_PASTED_HERE | base64 --decode` command, it has the same effect as the online tool, that is, it decodes as gibberish.

Comment: Using Bash for this is probably going to give you more gray hairs than you would prefer. But for a start, replace the ad hoc pipeline with a proper JSON processor like `jq`.

Comment: Locale settings will affect what characters are considered as valid. Try `export LC_ALL=C` near the beginning of your script to enforce traditional POSIX byte=character semantics.

Comment: exporting LC_ALL=C has no effect.

Comment: Googling the error message suggests that the input isn't actually entirely base64. See e.g. http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/apiman-user/2015-October/000365.html -- Without access to a representative sample, it's hard to say what exactly is wrong with it.

Comment: `echo moo | base64 --decode >/dev/null` works fine while `echo moo.bar | base64 --decode >/dev/null` gets me "invalid character in input stream".  For the record, valid base64 is alphabetics, numbers, and a couple of mathematical symbols (`+`, `/`, `=` at the end of the stream for padding).

Comment: using the string that comes out of the jq method works fine, i just have to formalize the script, and i'll upload it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decoding base64 while using GitHub API to Download a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768678/decoding-base64-while-using-github-api-to-download-a-file)

Answer (score 2):

Add header [`Accept: application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#custom-media-types) to the GET.

Comment: This is the recommended way to control what content you want - see the documentation for more details: https://developer.github.com/v3/media/#git-blob-properties

Answer (score 0):

Following tripleee's advice, i've switched the extracting method to `jq`

```
file=randomFileName74894031264.txt

curl -H 'Authorization: token MY_TOKEN' https://github.com/api/v3/repos/MY_OWNER/MY_REPO/contents/MY_FILE > "$file"

encoded_str=($(jq -r '.content' "$file"))

echo "$encoded_str" | base64 -D
rm -f "$file"
```

This works when running from the command line, but when running as a script the stdout doesn't flush, and we only get the first few lines of the file.

I will update this answer when I've formalized a generic script.

Comment: You don't need a temporary file, `curl | jq -r .content | base64 -D` should do it.