# Github create or update file fails with 422 invalid Base64 encoding for MIME 64 encoding

Tags: github, mime-types, github-api, mime

https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.18/v3/repos/contents/#create-or-update-a-file

I am trying to call the above API using [github-api](https://github.com/github-api/github-api) library. The API fails with 422, invalid Base 64 encoding.

The library uses [MIME](https://github.com/github-api/github-api/blob/d1507f26668950508e0bf242c34cdb599003991a/src/main/java/org/kohsuke/github/GHContentBuilder.java#L71) type encoding. If I change to `Base64.encodeToString(content)`, github api accepts it.

My question is:

1. Does github not accept MIME type 64 encoding?
2. I need to add a header of some kind to say it is not *plain* 64 but MIME type(which breaks into chunks of 76 characters)?

Answer (score 0):

It could be linked to [github-api/github-api issue 638](https://github.com/github-api/github-api/issues/638):

> When we invoke [`org/kohsuke/github/GHContentBuilder.java#commit()`](https://github.com/github-api/github-api/blob/d1507f26668950508e0bf242c34cdb599003991a/src/main/java/org/kohsuke/github/GHContentBuilder.java#L105) with [`content`](https://github.com/github-api/github-api/blob/d1507f26668950508e0bf242c34cdb599003991a/src/main/java/org/kohsuke/github/GHContentBuilder.java#L82) length > 57
>
> The API fails with 422, invalid Base 64 encoding
>
> If we have a content `1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678` of length 58.
>
> I was able to fix this issue locally by using `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString()`

This is however linked to a [recent change](https://github.com/github-api/github-api/blame/d1507f26668950508e0bf242c34cdb599003991a/src/main/java/org/kohsuke/github/GHContentBuilder.java#L71).

Note that "[GitHub Rest API V3 'Other Authentication Methods'](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/)" includes:

> The API supports Basic Authentication as defined in RFC2617 with a few slight differences.
>
> The main difference is that the RFC requires unauthenticated requests to be answered with 401 Unauthorized responses.
> In many places, this would disclose the existence of user data. Instead, the GitHub API responds with 404 Not Found.
> This may cause problems for HTTP libraries that assume a 401 Unauthorized response. The solution is to manually craft the Authorization header.

So a MIME encoding might nit be supported by [`github-api/github-api`](https://github.com/github-api/github-api) because of those RFC2617 requirements [which are not followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951561/use-invoke-webrequest-with-a-username-and-password-for-basic-authentication-on-t#comment44342253_27951845).

---

[Liam Newman](https://github.com/bitwiseman) from [CloudBees](https://www.cloudbees.com/) [comments](https://github.com/github-api/github-api/issues/638#issuecomment-565587304):

> The change you linked ([#631](https://github.com/github-api/github-api/pull/631) 'Remove dependency on apache commons-codec') hasn't been publish in a release yet - if you're you using v1.101 it doesn't have this change.
>
> I'm pretty sure I specifically used the MIME encoding because the non-MIME produced an error. Also, if you look at what comes back from GitHub it is MIME encoded.

See "[Decoding base64 while using GitHub API to Download a File](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54302528/6309)"

Comment: Yeah I raised that issue myself :) I understand the behavior. I am curious why Base64 is ok but not MIME Base64

Comment: @Hexy I always look at the username to check if I am not referencing an issue raise by the OP... but I did not double-check the picture associated with that account!

Comment: @Hexy Maybe the RFC2045-MIME variant of Base64 is not fully supported, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27951845/6309

Comment: Yes, that could be the case. I will reach out to Github directly then.