# node buffer to base64

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm wondering why my node-express code is not working while making base64

post.image is mongodb buffer

to string

```
posts.map((post, i) => {
    post.image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + new Buffer(post.image, 'base64')
})

posts.map((post, i) => {
    console.log(post.image)
})
```

it gives me buffer of result oㅅo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do Base64 encoding in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182315/how-to-do-base64-encoding-in-node-js)

Comment: I tried with this post but failed It doesn't work

Comment: Failed in what way? It clearly shows how to convert a `Buffer` object to a base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

mongoose schema was the problem

changing Buffer to Mixed fixed it