# golang base64 encoding vs nodejs buffer base64 encoding

Tags: node.js, string, go, encoding, base64

I'm using a piece of software that base64 encodes in node as follows:

```
const enc = new Buffer('test', 'base64')
```

`console.log(enc)` displays:

```
<Buffer b5 eb 2d>
```

I'm writing a golang service that needs to interoperate with this. But I can't reproduce the above result in go.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    b64 "encoding/base64"
)

func main() {
    // Attempt 1
    res := []byte(b64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte("test")))
    fmt.Println(res)
    // Attempt 2
    buf := make([]byte, 8)
    b64.URLEncoding.Encode(buf, []byte("test"))
    fmt.Println(buf)
}
```

The above prints:

```
[100 71 86 122 100 65 61 61]
[100 71 86 122 100 65 61 61]
```

both of which are rather different from node's output. I suspect the difference is that node is storing the string as bytes from a base64 string, while go is storing the string as bytes from an ascii/utf8 string represented as base64. But haven't figured out how to get go to do as node is doing!

I skimmed the go source for the encoding, then attempted to find the Node source for Buffer, but after a little while hunting decided it would probably be much quicker to post here in the hope someone knew the answer off-hand.

Comment: `new Buffer('test', 'base64')` *decodes* “test” as base64. Did you mean `new Buffer('test', 'ascii').toString('base64')`?

Comment: Ooh well now that's interesting; the string `"test"` is a jwt signing key. And the software in question appears then to be using `"thingsboardDefaultSigningKey"` as a b64 string. Thanks for your comment, you may have answered my question. Back in a minute!

Comment: @Ry-, thanks a lot, icza has posted the same in an answer, I'm going to award the tick to that. Sorry I can't split it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This constructor:

```
new Buffer('test', 'base64')
```

Decodes the input string `test`, using `base64` encoding. It does not encode the `test` using base64. See the [reference](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_string_encoding):

> ```
> new Buffer(string[, encoding])
> ```
>
> - `string`  String to encode.
> - `encoding`  The encoding of `string`. **Default:** `'utf8'`.

The equivalent Go code would be:

```
data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("test")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("% x", data)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pnHLApLtmxt)):

```
b5 eb 2d
```

To encode in Node.js, use (for details see [How to do Base64 encoding in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182315/how-to-do-base64-encoding-in-node-js)):

```
Buffer.from("test").toString('base64')
```

Comment: You've very thoroughly answered the question, you can stop editing! Thank you!