# Decoding a base64 encoded password in Node.js that was encoded in PHP

Tags: php, node.js, openssl, base64, decoding

How can I decode a base64 string in Node.js that was encoded in PHP like:

```
base64_encode(openssl_encrypt ('password', "AES-256-CBC",  'keyforthepassword',  OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, '6114'))
```

6114 is an ID of a person.

To decode this in PHP, I would run:

```
openssl_decrypt(base64_decode ('encoded_password'), "AES-256-CBC", 'keyforthepassword', OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, '6114')
```

**How can I do the above decrypting in Node.js?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do Base64 encoding in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182315/how-to-do-base64-encoding-in-node-js)

Comment: Check out the [Base64 encodings and decodings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) document from Mozilla.

Comment: Do you just need the base 64-decoded string, or do you also want to decrypt the password?

Comment: I need the decoded format. The password the user entered is what  i need.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string=<get your string here>;
new Buffer(string,'base64').toString('ascii');
```

Comment: It's only the base64 decoding, you'd still need to AES decrypt

Comment: Can you give me the complete code for getting the actual text?