# Convert binary data written in MongoDB to string in NODE JS

Tags: node.js, string, mongodb, binary, buffer

Guys help me to convert this

```
let a = Buffer.from('aaaaaaa', 'binary').toString('base64');
```

I need to convert 'a' into string.
I have converted to binary data to write it  in MongoDB.
Now I want to do the opposite.
How can I do this in Node JS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do Base64 encoding in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182315/how-to-do-base64-encoding-in-node-js)

Comment: @Stamos it's not a duplicate

Comment: Hi, could you add a sample document to the question?