# how to Convert binary data into string (using socket.io-parse)?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, binary

I am tring to convert a website's data which was been send in binary though websocket.

I saw it use socket.io-parse, but still can not know how he transfer the string data into binary data.

I am working for server days.

there is some binary data i copy it into base64 data:

```
data1 = 'BIIAAAAKBS9nL2JqA2JldAoDRVRIEgYwLjAwMDUaATAgAA=='


data2 = 'BAIFL2cvYmoNcmVjZW50LXJlc3VsdApXCNy8QxIgNjkxODk5MGZjMDc1NDNiMTkyMTUyZWIxYzYyOTcxNmMYxKwBKgRET0dFQgMxMDBKBC0xMDBQFFoBEmC+3xRqCktkaHR2amV0cGJyBWhlYWQ0'

data3 = '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'
```

i Tried use

```
    var base_64_str = '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';
    // var base_64_str = 'BAIFL2cvYmoNcmVjZW50LXJlc3VsdApXCNy8QxIgNjkxODk5MGZjMDc1NDNiMTkyMTUyZWIxYzYyOTcxNmMYxKwBKgRET0dFQgMxMDBKBC0xMDBQFFoBEmC+3xRqCktkaHR2amV0cGJyBWhlYWQ0';
    // var base_64_str = 'BAIFL2cvYmoKcGxheWVyLWJldAjpqCEQAhip71siAkpCKIDQ28P0AjBkOLAJ';

    const {encode, decode} = require('base64-arraybuffer');

    console.log('base_64_str',base_64_str);
    var binary_data = decode(base_64_str);

    console.log('binary_data',binary_data);
```

wanna to decode it into normal string

Comment: I just realized that you work in nodejs environment, you should have said that you work in Nodejs environment. Lol, but I should have look at the require statement. From the question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182315/how-to-do-base64-encoding-in-node-js. You can use the Buffer.from(base_64_str, 'base64').toString("ascii") or the Buffer.from(ascii_str, "ascii").toString("base64"). This question should be: "how do I convert base64 in nodeJS to str or str to base64".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do Base64 encoding in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182315/how-to-do-base64-encoding-in-node-js). I flagged this because, if asked and tagged correctly, this is a duplicated question. Nonetheless, it was an uncertain decision as the way this question was asked may have value for other programmers that use socket.io.