# Displaying a mySQL LONGBLOB as an image in EJS template using Node.js & Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to display a `BLOB` from from a `mySQL` table as an image in an `EJS` file but I cannot figure out how to do it. `latestlistings[0].photo` is the image I need to display. This is how my EJS file looks like where I need to display the image

```
<div>
  <%if (latestLocations[0]) {%>
    <%=latestLocations[0].address%>,
    <%=latestLocations[0].city%>,
    <%=latestLocations[0].province_state%>,
    <%=latestLocations[0].country%>
  <%}%>
  <%if (latestListings[0]) {%>
    <%=latestListings[0].price%>
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<%= latestListings[0].photo %>"/>
  <%}%>
</div>
```

I'm not modifying the variable at all when I pass it into the EJS template. I'm pulling it straight from the database where it's stored as a `LONGBLOB`. When I load the page, I just get an image icon which looks like this [image]. When I print out the variable right before passing it into the EJS template, it looks like this
`photo: <Buffer 49 4d 47 5f 32 34 35 35 2e 6a 70 67>`. I've been trying for ages trying to get this to work so any help is appreciated!

Comment: `<Buffer 49 4d 47 5f 32 34 35 35 2e 6a 70 67>` is not a base64 encoded string. Encode your buffer as base64 string and it should work.

Comment: I am passing the image from the HTML form into the database through an INSERT statement in mySQL and it is stored like that. Do you know how I could encode it in base64?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6182519/5781499