# how to specify binary data in jquery post function

Tags: jquery, post, upload, binary

I have screenshot as binary string.
I'd like to post some data to server using $.post() function.

My code:

```
var filename = "screenshot.jpg":
var filedataUrl = "";// string like 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4A .....'

$.post(serverUrl, {
title: title
name: name

/*here must be my file */

}, function(response) {
                alert('ok');
});
```

How can I specify parameter as attached file?

Comment: You may be interested by the answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148065/how-to-post-binary-file-from-jquery-client-to-java-server-using-rest

Answer (score 8):

Technically base64 is a text representation of binary data - if you are fine with this above answers are correct. If you want to send real binary data you have to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

If I'm reading your question correctly you are saving html "screenshot" to canvas element. If so instead of reading `toDataURL` you should use [toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob). This will give you binary data that we can send using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

```
var form = new FormData();

form.append('image', blob, 'image.jpg');
```

Above can be send using regular `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST', 'http://foo.com/submitform.php');
request.send(form);
```

Working example -> [codepen](http://codepen.io/frontendguy/pen/ORBJEz)

If you will look into chrome inspector you will see that correct multipart request is created:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryGWsPW93HnMPQFcXB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundaryGWsPW93HnMPQFcXB--
```

You can also send above form with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://foo.com/submitform.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: form,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
});
```

**Update**

Just saw your notice about handling file upload on server side in PHP. Uploaded file is available in $_FILES array:

```
<?php
    $uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "File was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    }
    echo 'File info:';
    print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `data`

Example:

```
$.post({
  url: serverUrl,
  data: {
    'fileasstring': filedataUrl
  },
  success: function(response) {
    alert('ok');
  }
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do a few things.

First you will need to breakup the filedataUrl. You want only the base64 data, not the rest. Then use the methods in [Base64 encoding and decoding in client-side Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820249/how-do-i-base64-encode-and-decode-using-javascript) to base64 decode the string into variable holding binary data.

Then include that variable in your post request.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can upload the image using a filename. You may need to create a form with file input element where the user can choose a file (not through javascript).

Then submit the form using AJAX.

Comment: I yet have image. it's browser screenshot. 
I only need to pass it as a file.

Comment: In that case, best option is to convert the file to base64 and post it via ajax. @Ariel's answer would be appropriate for you.

Answer (score 2):

`base64` encoded image is also a normal string. You can pass it as a `data` to the jQuery POST.

It will be like the following.

```
var filename = "screenshot.jpg":
var filedataUrl = "";// string like 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4A .....'

$.post(serverUrl, {
  title: title,
  name: name,
  image: filedataUrl,
})
.done(function(res){
  alert('ok')
})
```