# Decrypt Salesforce text blob Body via Javascript

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code

I have some Javascript where I extract the Body of a static resource file:

```
function test() {
    var query = sforce.connection.query("Select Body from StaticResource where Name = 'StaticResourceFile'");
    var records = query.getArray("records");
    var body = records[0].Body;
```

I have access to the body now, but it appears to be encrypted.  How do I decrypt it?

Via Apex, you can do it like this, but with Javascript not so:

```
Blob blob = [Select Body from StaticResource where Name = 'StaticResourceFile'].Body;
string body = blob.toString();  // actual file contents!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of bronsoja's answer, I searched around for a Salesforce-provided Base64 method.  I found one, in the AJAX toolkit file 'connection.js':

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/soap/ajax/22.0/connection.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
   function test() {
      var test = sforce.connection.query("Select Body from StaticResource where Name = 'StaticResourceFile'");
      var records = test.getArray("records");
      var contents = sforce.Base64Binary.prototype.decode(records[0].Body);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If [this](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_staticresource.htm) is the object you are interacting with it looks like the data is probably Base64 encoded.  You will need to decode it somehow.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820249/how-do-i-base64-encode-and-decode-using-javascript) seems to cover a number of options to perform the decoding in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  See my answer; you helped me get to it!