# Access HTTP Authentication info from Javascript

Tags: javascript, security, http-authentication

Is it possible to access the username (and optionally password), currently used for HTTP authentication from Javascript code on the page?

Comment: only if its stored in cookies or is entered in login form  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: In this answer I explain how to access a page or service via ajax that requires basic http authentication.**

If you mean [basic http authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), then it should be possible (I have never tried it myself).

Basic authentication means that you add the http header `Authorization` to your request, and the [`XmlHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest) object supports adding custom headers with the method [`setRequestHeader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader%28%29).

The http header looks like this:

```
Authorization: Basic {authentication token}
```

where the authentication token is constructed like this:

```
authentication token := base64(username + ":" + password)
```

Javascript doesn't have standard functions to encode to Base64, but [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820249/how-do-i-base64-encode-and-decode-using-javascript) shows you how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I meant is to access the credential used to retrieve the current HTML page. Like `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTH_USER']` on the server-side.

Comment: @vbence - Well, then I don't think it is possible. There is no API available in javascript to get this information.