# How to write a non-english character cookie using javascript and let php reads it properly

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, utf

my websites sometimes needs to read a javascript cookie using php but sometimes I get weird character set from some users like this `#16 3CFJ) DD%J,'1 while for some users it reads it properly. therefore, I think the problem is in the client-side. I use this method to write cookies:

```
    var expireDate = new Date();
        expireDate.setMonth(expireDate.getMonth() + 1);
    var value="Sami";
    document.cookie = "name="+value+";path=/;expires="+expireDate.toGMTString();
```

and this `$_COOKIE['name']`to read it using php.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies cant be handled using headers. So,

Encode your cookie using `base64_encode()` and decode it using `base64_decode()` to read it.

To encode/decode in Javascript, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/247261/295264) answer might help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820249/how-do-i-base64-encode-and-decode-using-javascript

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi, Thats a php function. Your question is tagged, PHP ain't it?

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi, Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/246801/295264) question too.

Comment: I use javascript to write and php to read. therefore this feature should exist in both. I checked ur link and doesnt say any thing about IE. isnt there something has do with utf-8 like setting javascript to write in utf-8.

Comment: btoa and atob only work properly for ASCII based strings. therefore I cant use it here.