# i want to fetch the total user count of given referral ids in table

Tags: php, mysql

hi i want to fetch the total user count of given referral ids in table
i have tried using left join but i am getting duplicate results from mysql.

```
i am attaching of screenshot of my table.
when user register we ask the sponser id which is actually the referral id 
of other user.
```

[image: table containing the referral id and sponser id]

Comment: It's not really `dataType: 'html'` now is it? :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you need ajax anyway. `collage.php` returns a valid image, so you can use the link used for your ajax call as the `img` tag `src` url. Just pass any variables you may need through the query string.

Example:

```
var queryString = $('#' + form).serialize();
$('#image').html('<img src="collage.php?' + queryString  + '"/>');
```

Comment: thanks your answers worked like charm..but i am sending array of images to collage.php.. it didn't work at all .but it works for two or one images instead !

Comment: Can you explain? Are you using `collage.php` several time on the same page or is it that `collage.php` returns more than one image?

Comment: <form><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $photo['source'];?>" name="collage_each[]"/></form>  This is the code i am sending to collage.php which takes all images and creates collage.. $photo[source] contains address of images in foreach loop..

Comment: When returning an image via `Imagejpeg` you can only return **one** image. In your specific case I'd suggest you take the photo sources into an js array and create `img` tags passing each `src` a source for a different photo as a queryString. Change `collage.php` into a method which only takes one photo at a time.

Comment: Another idea is to save the images to your server (if at all possible) and then returning a json containing a list of the new photos urls. You might wanna make sure you don't recreate an already saved image, depends on your demands.

Comment: nope.. my collage.php script takes an array of images i have tested it multiple times.. my question is can your querystring can serialise an array of images in am array like.. like <img src="$photo[source]" collage[]> .so can it take collage[] and serialize it

Comment: Does `collage.php` returns a `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`? Because if so then it doesn't make sense of me. I may need some more code to understand what you're doing or you could try and explain to me what does `collage.php` returns.

Comment: header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); it returns valid image

Comment: Ok, I may seem to understand my confusion. Do you take multiple sources and create a collage, a single image containing them? It sounds like your problems are on the server-side, so basically this answers your question. If you need more advice with your code may I suggest opening a new question, posting the relevant code there? Because I can't really help you when I have no idea what your code does.

Answer (score 1):

Change the JS to:

```
function post(form)
 { loading(1); 
   $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'image/jpeg',
            url: 'collage.php',
            data: $('#'+form).serialize(), 
            success: function(data) 
      { $('#image').html('<img src="data:'+base64_encode(data)+'"') }
           });
   return false; }
```

See [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820249/how-do-i-base64-encode-and-decode-using-javascript?lq=1) for information about implementing `base64_encode` in JS.

Comment: Thanks. I moved the base64 encoding into the JS.

Comment: That is a nice solution, yet I still see no reason for implementing `base64_encode` in this specific case. Also, IE8- has a 32KB limitation on using base64 urls. You have to take it into consideration in case your image might be as big or even bigger.

Comment: I have to send an array of images to collage.php  ..your code doesn't seem to be good to me..

Comment: I didn't change anything regarding what you're sending to collage.php, just how you display what it returns. If you want to put the image data directly in an `<img>` tag, you have to use the `data:` prefix followed by a base64 encoding of the data. Normally the `src` attribute contains the URL to get the data from, which is iMoses solution.

Answer (score 0):

In php manual, describe the function imagejpeg( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality ]] )

```
imagejpeg() creates a JPEG file from the given image
```

An image resource, returned by one of the image creation functions, such as

```
imagecreatetruecolor()
```

or

```
resource imagecreatefromjpeg ( string $filename )
```

then you can use imagejpeg to output an image