# how to make an MTOM soap message manually?

Tags: javascript, soap, mtom

Currently I am handling soap messages using javascript in client side. Now I have come up with MTOM request and response. In server side, I can convert files to/from binary64 format using axis. I have no idea (and couldn't find a way) how to do it in javascript.

Comment: Usually you do not need that in JavaScript, because the data you usually need in JavaScript can be simply used as _data URI_, like `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Base64 encoding and decoding in client-side Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820249/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-client-side-javascript)

Comment: @Tadeck I kind of didn't get the point :D I don't know about data URIs. Is there any full example out there? If that weird string is the binary64 format of a file(here a *.png), how is it produced? tnx

Comment: That string is actually base64-encoded file, and the browser understands it correctly (it needs a type, which is `image/png`, and the content, which is base64-encoded). The browser displays a file without requesting any server. The example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/VPfzy/. You can generate similar strings by one of online generators (google it) or just by base64-encoding any file (locally) and including its type in similar manner. Really simple after you get it.