# Need decryption script

Tags: javascript

I have this encryption code in javascript and its decryption was written in other language which I dont know. But I want to have a decryption of that in javascript ! Can any one help me on this.

```
function getEncryptedPassword(str) {
var keyStr = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP' +
    'QRSTUVWXYZabcdef' +
    'ghijklmnopqrstuv' +
    'wxyz0123456789+/' +
    '=';
var unEncPw = escape(str), output = '', i = 0;
var chr1, chr2, chr3 = '';
var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = '';

do {
    chr1 = unEncPw.charCodeAt(i++);
    chr2 = unEncPw.charCodeAt(i++);
    chr3 = unEncPw.charCodeAt(i++);

    enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
    enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
    enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
    enc4 = chr3 & 63;

    if (isNaN(chr2)) {
        enc3 = enc4 = 64;
    } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
        enc4 = 64;
    }

    output = output +
        keyStr.charAt(enc1) +
        keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
        keyStr.charAt(enc3) +
        keyStr.charAt(enc4);
    chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = '';
    enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = '';
} while (i < unEncPw.length);

return output;
}
```

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Help you with what? If you already have a "decryption" function, why don't you translate it?

Answer (score 2):

Your "encryption" turned out to be just base-64.  This isn't encryption at all... just another encoding.

You can encode/decode base64 in JS.  See here:  [Base64 encoding and decoding in client-side Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2820249/362536)