# How to encode an image to base64 using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

I'm trying to encode an image (jpg) to base64 using IE9. I tried the following code:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = document.getElementById('myImage').width; 
    canvas.height = document.getElementById('myImage').height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('myImage'), 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
```

I got the error : DOM Exception: SECURITY_ERR (18) when I call toDataURL method.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Base64 encoding and decoding in client-side Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820249/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-client-side-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use php or any other server side languages for encode an image to a base64 encoding.Use jquery ajax for this purpose , encode it on server side and pass it to the client side .

You can encode text to base64 encoding .There is a nice project in Codeplex [Click here](http://jsbase64.codeplex.com/)

Iam not sure you can encode images ,give a try .

Answer (score 0):

Due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you can't encode a canvas when you drew on it something coming from another origin than your page, except if :

- the drawn image was served with relevant [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)
- you serve it through a proxy so that the browser thinks it's the same origin

Note that if you open your page in `file://`, then any image will be seen as from another origin.

Comment: wait, you "can't" encode it if was served with cors or a proxy?

Comment: You can't encode the image if it was served from another domain without CORS. If it was served with the right CORS header then it's fine.

Comment: @dandavis I'm not a native English speaker but doesn't "apart" convey the same meaning than "except" here ?

Comment: well, it was enough that i didn't understand it without my morning coffee. you could say "apart from cases where" instead of "except if"...

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for that English lesson :)