# Storing and Retrieving images from DB2 using Worklight SQL Adapters?

Tags: javascript, db2, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm trying to store images in `DB2` Database as `BLOB` contents. I used `JS` to convert the image content to `base64`.

```
 function loadImageFileAsURL()
{
var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
if (filesSelected.length > 0)
{
    var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        var textAreaFileContents = document.getElementById
        (
            "textAreaFileContents"
        );

        textAreaFileContents.innerHTML = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        var ImgContent = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        $("#IMAGE").attr("src",ImgContent);

    };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
}
}
```

Now I need to convert this `base64` content to binary and store them to my `DB2` Database. Is there any way to do this in JavaScript?

And how to fetch this data from the database and display it on my mobile app using `Adapters`. ?

Comment: why do you convert to base64, just upload the file with FormData and read the file as stream in your server code.

Comment: There is no server Code in Worklight. Take a look at this http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/05_01_Overview_of_client_technologies.pdf

Comment: you can write a custom javascript procedure in your adapter. where do you use the code show in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you not simply store the image as encoded to base64 in database? I think this would be better in your scenario...

1. You receive an image
2. You use some library to handle the encoding to base64
   Review this question: [Base64 encoding and decoding in client-side Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820249/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-client-side-javascript)
3. You store the image-now a string, in the database
4. When you need to display the image in the app, fetch the contents and decode it (see step 2)

Comment: I ll use this approach and you my feedback