# Fetch image from the tomcat server using Worklight Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I need to fetch and display a image from apache tomcat server and display in the html  tag.

Edit: trying to encoding it:

If i try to fetch the image using http adapter , the outcoming result is a string and I dont know which encoding it follows,
Any ways I passed that value to java which will encode it in base64. The problem is that the base64EncodedString is not the expected encodedValue`
The invoke worklight adapter procedure value is

```
{
   "errors": [
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "responseHeaders": {
      "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
      "Content-Length": "5623",
      "Content-Type": "image\/jpeg",
      "Date": "Wed, 09 Jul 2014 05:37:39 GMT",
      "ETag": "W\/\"5623-1380193498000\"",
      "Last-Modified": "Thu, 26 Sep 2013 11:04:58 GMT",
      "Server": "Apache-Coyote\/1.1"
   },
   "responseTime": 484,
   "statusCode": 200,
   "statusReason": "OK",
   "text": "����\0\u0010JFIF\0\u0001\u0002\0\0d\0d\0\0��\0\u0011Ducky\0\u0001\0\u0004\0\0\0P\0\0��\0\u000eAdobe\0d�\0\0\0\u0001��\0�\0\u0002\u0002\u0002\u0002\u0002\u0002\u0002\u0002\u0002\u0002\u0003\u0002\u0002\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0003\u0002\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0004\u0004\u0004\u0004\u0004\u0005\u0006\u0005\u0005\u0005\u0005\u0005\u0005\u0006\u0006\u0007\u0007\b\u0007\u0007\u0006\t\t\n\n\t\t\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\u0001\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0005\u0004\u0005\t\u0006\u0006\t\n\u000b\t\u000b\n\u000f\u000e\u000e\u000e\u000e\u000f\u000f\f\f\f\f\f\u000f\u000f\f\f\f\f\f\f\u000f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f��\0\u0011\b\0b\0�\u0003\u0001\u0011\0\u0002\u0011\u0001\u0003\u0011\u0001��\0�\0\u0001\0\u0003\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\u0007\b\t\u0006\u0005\u0004\n\u0003\u0001\u0001\0\u0001\u0005\u0001\u0001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\u0001\u0002\u0005\u0006\u0007\b\u0003\u0004\u0010\0\u0001\u0003\u0004\u0001\u0003\u0002\u0004\u0002\u0004\n\u000b\u0001\0\0\0\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\0\u0011\u0005\u0006\u0007!\u0012\b1\u0013Aa\"\u00142\u0015Qq�\u0016�Bbr�#34t\u0018�c��$�u&\u00178\t7\u0011\0\u0002\u0001\u0002\u0004\u0004\u0001\t\u0007\u0004\u0003\0\0\0\0\0\0\u0001\u0002\u0011\u00031\u0012\u0004\u0005!AQ\u0006�aq�\"2Br\u0013\u0007��b��\u0015�R�\u0014�#%��\0\f\u0003\u0001\0\u0002\u0011\u0003\u0011\0?\0��\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�>9�\u001c~.2�d�G�Do�IR�C-���d\u0001�5�����=�(�s�Q^�zٱr�[���$��#���z$��\u0016&�zB�6И�*?�7P��\n���=��CQm����\\.�Z�Q�+\u0017\u0012�_�v ߨ�\u000f���j\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u000eko�����Sb�\u000e�q�w6�6S�����~jQ\u0002�\0\u000f_�[7���٤���\u0011Xux%��\u0018�\n�n��jab\u0018���b߂�\f���<��w)����T~�\u001aI\fGA=\u0010�\/`\u0007��>��\\Ǽ�z���z\/v+�Wپg@�{N�m��ٍ:�zO� d�\u001c�ZK�c8C�28,�\nS91r�ܛ��\u0005O(�P�Y�}�=}�(ا�_�[��Obwu�\u001e�\u001aK�r�7�5�$��o�X\/iS�p.��Z�2�يWb��淚 2�>xt���i�@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0005s�mr\u0013����F\u001cͲ$���a�~W\u001f�j��T\\��\n`���S��\u0019���\u0017�N��O�\u001f���\u001cu����5�NE�z\f��S7�Z\u0013�\u0014\u001f��c�=�z;z��ś����WU�<M��j���^�m�J.����]~h�5Dq�i�8Ȱ��e�a���\u001b[\/\u0015�\n�\u001d�Y**�#��~\u0002��{�%�\\��\u0018�K#I'\u0019U$�9<\u001a��5\u000fik�os��9<��M�UF�~U�}L�mKJЦ���T\u000bjM‚��E���Αm4�&�Mq��&2��ư�N�3�\u0012&��\u000e#�\f�{e�l\u001e���S��~��\u0016�蔽�q9�zy�wT_�͕J��ƕ�N4������\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002���I��T��Ω-=)��2\u0014:5!��ҍ�����\u0002j��;<wm\n�3�ڬ_I.1~�\u000f�R�nr�up����|\u001f��С|e\u0002^\/�5�l�\u0015\u001al\u001c�b\\u�$8�RT\u000f�\"���4��W\u0015%\u001b�k�U����\/�\u0017nA�2�S�\t���\u000f_Ԙ]�-j��\u0012={\u001b�L\u000fԥ\u0015��Ͼ�nym����O<��Տ���\u0018gӭ�4����^w�_v_I\u0001�\u0017\u0016�G!�l�\u0016���Vkd���;X\u0005m�?J�R \u000f�\0�Ԋ�{#c�G\\�\\_�Z�������L�{�Yv\u0016��Ӫ߾�Ay�9y�q�Z�W�*��A�?1���\u000e���j��K��i�i��oEP\u0016I��r�����[����ԩ.o��}�[�]���ݟwIu&��6nn�S��o\/���m\u0006\u00135���8��\u0016ky\fVQ�ȃ1�t�\n\u001f��\u0004z\u0010z�pz��#%%U��\u001a�-�-�Y�\u0017\u0019�ѧ��渣Ԫ��P\n\u0001@(\n%�fŰk�������`�����\u000e��;\u0015N$0\bJ�JI \u001f��D2U�\u0017-���^�����e�\u000e��%��^\\��\u00111Ԥ)�\n�l\u0005�Z0�ڙ��盶=\u000fW߳Q'e6l�\\S\/e�1\u0019����\u0004�\u000bWjB\u001b \0��I\u0007��@� ǩ��su�\"<�KP2�e���u�\u000e�ˬ�*I6\u0017\tq�\u001b\u001b^��\f�O�\u001b�\u0015��i��$�j&Yjv\u0016v+7��.2�VP\t$%i)X\u0004�\n�ͯP�&:�(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002����]����G�ۚ��\0\"}���\0 #�}������s���;mj��\u0006��$�\u0001@(\b\/q���N��bc�\u0013ڏ�6���)fA��B��~u�o]��\0���,�}+��R3�\0\u0017�|�g���\n��\u000f� �x�\n��y���F�?�J����aYlw\u0017\u0010�\f��?�(\u0015\u000f�V��t�m���ՖH%�\/US�||M���8�m���i\u001c�o�~���p�!�-w�4�s\u000f�Ƶ1+�׳��Y�+�ӜJ\\�\b��Z\u0001.\u0011���Ѕ\n�{f�\u001d�E\n$}�j��7�̰^D�����-�S=��xq���AUJ~yq���C��\0�7\u001f\u00199�ߓ�v1�#^¸E�~Gd�j\u001f�Hm-\u000fԳW��[��i��d�co��'�%�c\u000f\u0006�~�z~\u0010���V ��Iv���͛���5$��$¹6\u0001�\u000b�\u0003����b�۵4���\u000f���h|�-���}h�1��8�(���2�yE��W��E\0�*w�\u001c\u0019�\u001cÚל�7f�l\u00166\u000b�䢸�ﾷ;��a�\u0010�'�ԫ�S\u0006|nx�n�krġ[s�Z~�\u0017:\f����m�\u0004���<\u0012\u0014S�h�\u0013���A?�}����Cq�S\u0019{\u001b�l��7KO9\n%��I$���\u000b�(�,��?��\0� �� λP�3c\u0011�c���\\�\"v?\u0001��\u001d�\u0012'g��㒙\u0001\u001d�J}V\u000fSSȃ��G�����j�,\u0013�\u001dw\u001b=9)2r\u000bB�=%-��g����!\u000e��**���I\u0012hόڦ\u000fO��[\u001d����[��g�sx�=��K��]J\t\0�\0U`Ք\u0002���\u0003qP�+�\0\/�ʜ��m{T\u000eE����\u001fmz�\u0012D��KHC\n�B�\u0012P�֕\u001b +���\u0014L���$�\u0003�\f\u001d\u0017f�Γ�c1\u001f\u0013�k2d�T_fJ���`���\u00048�\u0010�v�\u000b\u0005t6�\u0004��7m��Ë�]K3'\u0001\u0010c���\u0013�:Y���-ķ\u001f�l��\tB;�\u0004wwu�\u0005\u0012\f�|l��tݷX䍫f�q����S\\T�N�\u001fy\u0019a��K~Җ�,\u0015\u0002��lI�l\u001c\u0016��9d\u001b�g\u0007$B�f�㯱�rt�$���Iu\u0016\n�\u000e����@u��< \u0010�{�ɐx�k�N��3�\\h�rN-��b����[��)W��)\u0017�q\u0006í�\u0003�$\u000f5�&�rU�?�i�\u0012\/�^F��'6�\u0012�3���9-���X��bo}��r�����G���>�\n�\u0002������L\n�{4�e���C�I*un�\u0005�e\bl\u0015(�b.���\u001e��\"��H\u001b�|K���n�v���\t��<��z�\u0016D��KQ�Y-���\u0014��,��\nT�\b��W��'�LW\u001b�i�q\u00133M�\u0006���d5\u0015��\u0011��\u000bZ���\u001cRTJ\u000fj� ^�K\u0006ú�]mƗ~�RP��Rl�cb,G�9EI4�FN-5ȥ�h*�f97��-#!\u0007���&i��E���)l�v� �-�~2H�\"��&[^����\u0018Z����^��S��U�\u0011�n^�o�������U�����,�\f�k)��2����29�̧f��:n�_yEkY�u'�VK)96�,�}&�֒�,ڊ� �b�$�$~��c��Ƽ%��\u001ek��M�3\u0019Сe��G�!h_Aդ�- C��YF��˴�<}'\u0018w�������`��?\f=T��ӗ�0\u001e^Fv\u001fl����r\u000eK\u0019�rV>k*�q��|��\u0010G�J�\"��ڕWS��؅�*�q)FPI��MQ��G跈wer?\u0018��Cr�\u001cK\u00122\n��\u0013(\u000fnJS�\u000e�@|�+�s�[R�\u001f�m�m[��\"���U�.1��h��ر�vc)\u001b\u0007��榕\bx�o͖S�^�v���{u�M\u0001���מ<��I��\u000fswUǦ3�\u0003��1�P!��q\n\u001e����.�7P$��T�U�\u0007\u000b�\/\u000e�|E+U��n�q :Է\"���#�:�\n\0��\u001f��z\u0001��`�y��\0V|p�\0o��TX��x`��\0�� ���\u0005\u0001�?x��g����v�,_��\u001csYl6Ko�\"v9�Kn�&Z�P\u0004\u001e�H5<�u<��ۅ�\u001cM�l��j&���a����5��[�I\b��\u0014����B\u0005��?O�\u0013\u0005E�י��O���:\n>��c]�B|)Q��KyQ��\0�\u0001n�P���7\u001e�,\u001e�\u001ai>@�6�kj�ʒ��t�\u0011oʛ%\n�_��T�Т����8��$}]\/��\u0001\n��VW���&��Ϋe��2�O��+ܻʐ�Y\0 Z���%ЀI�|=(\t#���\0v� ѱ��*�2��;�y�!�}B.����ۃ^�<��K�,x�4_u�*�+��J{�\u0002����H\u0015���\u001b�y�Z��9N^����[�Ɖ��J����Z�,!�� ��+�z$Z����q��7ɝ;\u001c�-�~k#\u0019�F຦�JAY�'�\"��x\u0003��\u0014Lw��)�z\u001ers�L��5\u001c(��\u001c}IJ\u0010\u0011�\u0012�l\0��@��p\\��o i�ܶ<b��Y��ƴU�ی�\n\u001e�����m:�z\\�؂X�P9cȸ�\u000e\u0004���ʕ��\u001f\u001f�\u0019\0,E��]S��\u000b��\u0003\u000e\u0002�ۼ|G�4\u00053�>2��\0#1s�i��3\u001f�L��asg�Qq��R��[i\t�N޷�~58\u0002\u0012\u001a��\/�l.���+;��nX�����\u0005��L\u0012��JW��h\n�I\"�t�'�|=�\u001a�)\n{)���N6:E���]i��qH\t�ᩃ��%�\f��w\u000bz\n�K���\u0011�\u001cϤ[�~\t���*J��$�I$)$X�=A\u0015�\u001d̝M]c�\0�\u0018$�(K�VM�LL\u001fiV�q�\\��߸.�}�����\n '���|�Yd���s����_��\u0016�5}��)���7����W]q�]}�\u001dyj[�\u001fU)F��j�t\\b��X#�W㾩��xK����K����m�W\u0005�˲ԩKec�˽��+,�A��SƇ\u0010w��op޵W�:�ͤ��)�#�Rg��ŏ�|\u0018�83q�[���\u0018r4��N�IB��A4\u0006F���Ȯ\u0019ޞ��[2��[��\\[��܌�\u0016j\\g�,m��\u0014����6���\u001f~�㿕���N˰!�\0���9:\u0003\/E��T��\u0012��\n��% ��\u0015����P-4�\u001f2����_\u001a�M#U��fP�<��r\u001abc\u000by��W\u0015N�M�ӆ���*�)?\"\u001f\u001fxo�^'�L,\t�r?\u0019�-�vTE��z\u000b������[�ࢰ���\u0015`\/�T�\b�`��H���nZ~�\"\u0003�g�S�y���dw�R_t��\u00131+Gsk� \u001e�4�>��:yw�����s��{+\ni���Ը�(�\u0017\u00031��A\u0003Ԇ�J�[,o��\fW\u0007�b�U\/l�2��N���J?0�B�$ w\u0010�>�[������EE\n���W��I��at<d�sYU��~#��8��~��\f�)�͏�!+���S�\u001f�b�g�\u0013����V��Է\"�3ytd���!�l#��z:�[m�[�v\u0001d��4�$_)||��G剛6���s�w\u0019\n;s~�\0\u001f\u001e�2�\u0016�nD��П^�Q0�\u001f�_\u0004�y����\u0018�\nC��\u0010\u001f�3!Ve��R܈�X�AWbJU�]6=\u000fp��N4]\u0013ͭ_\u001et\u001da����K�(?#\u001b��C�*Z���:�'��\u0010¯s{\\��\u0007E��2�7\u001de�m�u�FEnd6��\b���Le�o��}2Oj�7�}�� ���\0\/���h �\/�������\u001f ����^���Ͻ�z��w|�PZ�&8`s\u001f\u001f�\u0013\u0017\u001d��Z�;TuE(.,�\u001e�V���\/� \\�\u0002�\t6\u0006�2Jm�x��S�]���]Xa5����Yǲ8�\f㳑R[\u001e�q�<�)�)�\u0014!E'�]�\u00071�q���b�CW��\f4,���^����)F͗�䅸��R\u0007T���_ӣ�>�x��\u000e3�5��+�F�ٗ��\n���^��d!�\bP��.�M��p�\u001e����\u00145��$P\u0019�䧃���G}��\u00166W*���+\f4�\tS��yG�\nqF�m}���P�5h�m��kx�7�b}Z���t{�\\\"�\u000b�U��#8���%W�i�Q\u0015x��\u001a'�Zx�6dz{�\n������,���N��l�\0J�i��}}B�\u001d���ݺy�o�L�qx|q�fn���o\u001c�����8�8}\u001e;���d �!�� ��\u0010E�h*J���E�nZM�����MK�?W!��-&�T���ֲ��\u0015m>*����%_Yi�^\n\u0004(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u0005\0�\u0014\u0002�P\n\u0001@(\u000f��",
   "totalTime": 494,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}`.
```

Any Ideas will help me.

Answer (score 0):

1. From the question's title one will think that you use the Worklight Server as a file server - that is bad practice; you should not store files in your Worklight Server. Use a dedicated file hosting server
2. Why is the image a string to begin with? Did you or something else encode it (to base 64)? If this is the case then you need to base64 decode it; there are many existing questions on this subject matter.

Related questions:

- [Storing and Retrieving images from DB2 using Worklight SQL Adapters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164828/storing-and-retrieving-images-from-db2-using-worklight-sql-adapters)
- [post image using worklight http adapter proper format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249707/post-image-using-worklight-http-adapter-proper-format)

You could also use [Cordova's File API](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md).

- [How to send images through Worklight server without base64 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789628/how-to-send-images-through-worklight-server-without-base64-encoding)
- [Uploading large (and binary) files to Worklight adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762234/uploading-large-and-binary-files-to-worklight-adapter)

Comment: I am building a app which is required to fetch a image from the tomcat or someother server. How to fetch it using the worklight adapter.

Comment: Then use the encode/decode to/from base64  approach. It's your only option.

Comment: How to use,can you give any documentation for that

Comment: You need to find a JS library that is able to encode/decode image files to base64; please read online about encoding/decoding image files.

Comment: Is there a way to encode while getting the image from apache server using http adapter in worklight without going for js library

Comment: Maybe with some Java servlet that the adapter will point to. I don't know.