# javascript - base64 decode like bouncy castle in Java

Tags: javascript, encryption, base64, decode

We have a working code in Java that decrypts an encrypted string, and it gives us back the byte array.

```
byte[] decode = null;
decode = Base64.decode(encryptedString);
```

We need an equivalent version in client side: javascript.  Are there any available libraries?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820249/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-client-side-javascript

Comment: @hcs , i believe those doesn't return a byte array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out our code in crypto works fine, its return is on hex format however, and when we converted our byte[] in java code to hex, they turned out to be equivalent:

```
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encryptedString);
```

Lesson learned: On java it dealt with byte[] mostly, but on Crypto it makes use of hex.