# preview image not be shown using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I used this link for Convert an Image to byte array in Angular

[Convert an Image to byte array in Angular (typescript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66024416/convert-an-image-to-byte-array-in-angular-typescript)

but  src not bind to image for preview
my  typescript code is :

```
  upload() : void {
    const file = (document.querySelector('input[type=file]') as HTMLInputElement).files![0];
    const preview = document.getElementById('preview') as HTMLImageElement;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    let byteArray;
    reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
      // convert image file to base64 string
      console.log('base64', reader.result);
      **preview.src != reader.result;**
      byteArray = convertDataURIToBinary(reader.result);

      console.log('byte array', byteArray);
    }, false);
    if (file) {
      reader!.readAsDataURL(file);

    }

  }

}
function  convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI:any) {
  var base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(';base64,') + ';base64,'.length;
  var base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
  var raw = window.atob(base64);
  var rawLength = raw.length;
  var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

  for(let i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
    array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return array;
}
```

and my html is

```
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" width="300" height="300" />

<button (click)="upload()">Upload</button>

<img   id="preview">
```

My problem is this line that src is empty and the image not be shown

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't "target" the element from your typescript but instead use a data binding approach which is a go-to way in Angular.

In your HTML:

```
<img src="{{previewImage}}" *ngIf="previewImage">
```

In your typescript update the following snippet:

```
reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
      // convert image file to base64 string
      console.log('base64', reader.result);
      **preview.src != reader.result;**
      ...
```

into this:

```
reader.addEventListener("loadend", () => {
      // convert image file to base64 string
      console.log('base64', reader.result);
      this.previewImage = reader.result;
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did ... but when I define the variable 'previewImage', it is unknown for this section. I get this Property 'previewImage' does not exist on type 'FileReader'.ts(2339)

Comment: Please see my updated answer, was in a rush ... just change `reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {` into `reader.addEventListener("loadend", () => {` and that should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

Please save the reader result into a variable and use the same as the source to an img tag in HTML

TS File :

```
binaryImage : any;

...
this.binaryImage = reader.result;
...
```

HTML File:

```
<img src="{{binaryImage}}">
```

or

```
<div style="background-image: url({{binaryImage}});">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did ... but when I define the variable 'binaryImage', it is unknown for this section. I get this Property 'binaryImage' does not exist on type 'FileReader'.ts(2339)

Comment: Declare the binaryImage variable globally in  the ts file.