# Html pass data to new window using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to pass some JavaScript object to the new window opening. Below code  works fine when I open page in new tab.

```
              var url = "http://page1.html";
              var win = window.open(url, "_blank");
              win.myData = myData;
              win.focus();
```

And I am able to access the data on page1.html using

```
            var data = window.opener.myData;
```

But if opens the page in same tab using

```
              var win = window.open(url, "_self");
```

This method not works. I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'myData' of null` on second page.

How can I pass the data when open the new page in same tab.

Comment: You're going to have to use something like `localStorage` to do that.

Comment: try `window.self.myData`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: sharing data between tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366483/javascript-sharing-data-between-tabs)

Comment: Thanks I will check it.

Comment: You can use localStorage (as said above), cookies, query strings. Look at this question, there is a lot of explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Answer (score 1):

As comments suggested you could use a form of persistent storage such as a `cookie` or `localStorage`. However these may be blocked/disabled by the user via browser settings.

Passing your data as a `query parameter` appended to the url would seem the most straightforward and reliable option. There are considerations regarding this method, such as the maximum permissable length of a url; and privacy - urls will be stored in browser history, logged by the ISP etc.

The data will also need to be in a url-safe format. You can use `encodeUriComponent` for this, perhaps encoding it as a base64 string beforehand to avoid having the plaintext data in the url.

```js
var data = {
    thing: 'something here',
    otherThing: [{ name: 'zoo', size: 1 }, { name: 'far', size: 9001 }]
};

var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
var dataStringBase64 = window.btoa(dataString); // (optional)
var dataStringBase64Safe = encodeURIComponent(dataStringBase64);

var url = 'https://example.com?data=' + dataStringBase64Safe;
window.open(url, '_self');
```

On the new page (grabbing the desired query param, then reversing the steps):

```js
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); // supported on most modern browsers
var dataStringBase64Safe = urlParams.get('data');

var dataStringBase64 = decodeURIComponent(dataStringBase64Safe);
var dataString = window.atob(dataStringBase64);
var data = JSON.parse(dataString);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using Data URLs, with base64 encoded data,

ex:

```
var string = JSON.stringify({
name: "x",
age: 23
});

// Encode the String
var encodedString = btoa(string);
console.log(encodedString);

// Decode the String
var decodedString = atob(encodedString);
console.log(decodedString); // Outputs:  "{"name":"x","age":23}"
```

this way you can send even a image
[How to decode data:image/png:base64... to a real image using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636294/how-to-decode-dataimage-pngbase64-to-a-real-image-using-javascript)

[Read on Data Urls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)