# Get base64 string of a file in ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, base64

I am new to ionic and angular and right now I m trying to convert a file to base64 string. I am selecting file using cordova file plugin and the file could be image, pdf, doc or of any type. I have the full path to that file. How can I get the base64 string of that file? Can I use the file path to convert to base64 or what is the way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[phonegap-base64.](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-base64) It is cordova plugin and worked for me as well.

Comment: Thanks Harrish ;) The simplest, easiest and to the point solution

Comment: it is not working for pdf files and returning empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Use angular-base64 plugin for that. The link is here: https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64.
It is easy to use. Inject the dependency in module as:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['base64'])
    .controller('myController', ['$base64', '$scope',function($base64, $scope) {

            $scope.encoded = $base64.encode('a string');
            $scope.decoded = $base64.decode('YSBzdHJpbmc=');
    }]);
```

And,remember to include the reference in index.html.

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-base64/angular-base64.js"></script>
```

Comment: Firstly, Thanks a lot Alex. but what should be the param, it takes string as param but I have pdf/img file path as param so how and what should I pass as param?

Comment: If the param is image, you get the base64 encoded image and if the param is string you get the base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at this:

- [Converts files from file input into base64](https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64)

How to use it:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['base64'])
    .controller('myController', [

        '$base64', '$scope', 
        function($base64, $scope) {

            $scope.encoded = $base64.encode('a string');
            $scope.decoded = $base64.decode('YSBzdHJpbmc=');
    }]);
```

You could do this:

```
 var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(e)
    {
        // e.target.result contains the "string" of your file
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(yourfile);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot com.ulf. but what should be the param, it takes string as param but I have pdf/img file path as param so how and what should I pass as param?

Comment: Link only answers arent great - consider adding detail from both links in particular for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
file.toString('base64');
```

you can also try reading these since it is basically a framework build on JS

[Base64 encoding and decoding in client-side Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820249/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-client-side-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @WebDevNewbieGirl, what is file in this?

Comment: In my case that was a picture(object) encoded binary form. For other types I cannot guarantee if this solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ionic native plugin. So simple!

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64/?_gl=1*1pn9ojn*_ga*MTI1NzQzODk5Ny4xNjE1NTYxMzU2*_ga_REH9TJF6KF*MTYxODU1Mjk4OS45LjEuMTYxODU1MzA5Mi4w