# Gtmetrix fetch report using react native

Tags: json, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

am trying to fetch GTmetrix report using react native

am not good in react native please help me out here

Code:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      isLoading:true,
        dataSource:null,
        emailAddress: "Your email Address",
        passWord: "your password",
        apikey:'Your api key'
    }
}

async onFetchLoginRecords(props, callback) {
    var data = {
        email: this.state.emailAddress,
        // password: this.state.passWord,
        apikey:this.state.response
       };
       var myurl="https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/"
       try {
            const body = new FormData
            body.append("url", "https://example.com/")
            body.append("x-metrix-adblock", "0")
            body.append("", "\\")
            let response = await fetch(
                myurl,
                {
                //parameters: props.params || null,
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                    Authorization: "Your authorization"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
                }
            );
            if (response.status >= 200 || response.status < 300) {
                alert("authenticated successfully!!!");
                this.fetchapi(myurl);
            }
        } catch (errors) {
            console.log(errors);
        } 
} 
componentWillMount(){
    this.onFetchLoginRecords();
}

fetchapi= (myurl) => {
    fetch(myurl)
    .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
            isLoading:false,
             dataSource: response.resources
            });
            console.log(response);
      })
    .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

and i got this result error: [Invalid e-mail and/or Api key] i dint understand after writing correct e-mail and Api key and password. . . . .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is really late but the documetation stated

> The GTmetrix API uses **HTTP Basic Access Authentication** as its
> authentication mechanism. Use your e-mail address as the username and
> the API key as the password.

to do this using the fetch api
replace your `header.Authorization` : `"Your Authorization"`

```
headers: {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", 
  Authorization: "Your authorization"
},
```

with

```
 Authorization: `Basic ${encodeBase64(`${username}:${key}`)}`,
```

where **encodeBase64** is a function

```
/**
 * Encode a string of text as base64
 * @param {string} data The string of text.
 * @returns {string} The base64 encoded string.
 */
function encodeBase64(data) {
    if (typeof btoa === "function") {
        return btoa(data);
    } else if (typeof Buffer === "function") {
        return Buffer.from(data, "utf-8").toString("base64");
    } else {
        throw new Error("Failed to determine the platform specific encoder");
    }
}
```

Comment: I referenced the encode function from [kraenhansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503899/kraenhansen) or goto this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820249/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-client-side-javascript